# Read autofilled input value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, autofill

I have a UI that needs a class added to input containers if they are focused or have any text inside. I use jQuery to add/remove the class depending on focus state but the script also needs to run once on load in case the value is already filled in.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $jsInputs = $('.js-input');

    // Listeners
    $jsInputs.on('focusin', function(e) {
        var $input = $(this),
            $parent = $input.parent();

        $parent.addClass('is-active');
    });

    $jsInputs.on('focusout', function(e) {
        var $input = $(this),
            $parent = $input.parent();

        if (!$input.val()) {
            $parent.removeClass('is-active');
        }
    });

    // Run once to check for input already present
    $jsInputs.each(function(i,e) {
        if ($(e).val()) {
            $(e).parent().addClass('is-active');
        }
    })
})
```

This works fine for values added by the application itself but struggles with values autofilled by the browser. So far I've tried waiting until `window.onload` and triggering a `focusin` and `focusout` event programatically on the inputs, but none of those methods detect the autofilled text.

Is there a way to reliably read autofilled values in JS (vanilla or jQuery)? Disabling autofill could be a last resort but I really don't want to go there from a UX perspective...

Comment: Did you try with 'change' or 'onkeyup' events ?

Comment: Ah yes, the tip on `change` and the other question solved my problem - thanks guys! Will accept as duplicate